# Creating a warning message box using css

Tags: jquery, html, css, messagebox, requiredfieldvalidator

I want to create a warning message box for required field using css which should be exactly like this - [image: This is what i want]

So far I have achieved this something like this-https://jsfiddle.net/payalsuthar/352k4ope/
Here is my html code-

```
Name:<input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name"><br>
<div id="errname"><p id="sym">!</p>Please fill out this field.</div>

Address:<textarea></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Here is my css -

```
#errname{
  border:1px solid orange;
  border-radius:4px;
  width:250px;
  margin-top=100px;
  background-color:white;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:10px;
}
#sym{
  width:18px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:darkorange;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:14px;
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

But I want it to be exactly like the above image, I don't mind if it overlaps the next field and it should appear at the same position as in the above image.I know this is html required field validator message box but it is not working fine with me so I am creating one exactly like that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you've shown is the standard tooltip which is displayed in Chrome when the `required` attribute is set, but not met. Is there a reason you can't just use that?

Comment: ...also, what is the question here? I can see this being multiple duplicates.

Comment: I tried to use that with php desktop chrome application ,it is fully functional with that.i.e.it does not let me submit the form unless every field is filled  but the only problem is that it does not displays the message box.@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @Paulie_D..I want to create a message box exactly like the image provided above..And i have tried to do that to some extent but not fully achieved the required thing..

Comment: @Paulie_D..I have asked the question only after trying my best to achieve that..Let me ask you people,why are you people so reluctant to help others..I mean,I already tried to find a way out, researched enough, tried out most other things and have got the output to some extent now just that I am clueless about how to achieve that further ,so I posted it on stackoverflow..

Comment: @everyone...Has stackoverflow become a place to  down vote the questions instead of answering them?..even after they match your "Ask a question policy" and please whosoever downvoted my question please can i get a  justifiable reason for why my question is downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/352k4ope/4/

```
#name {
  position: relative;
}

#name::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 60px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

#name::after {
  content: url('http://67.media.tumblr.com/fdeec9480199afb3c6ed9c24b2aec9c5/tumblr_oaayc9r25Z1vaudwko1_75sq.png')'  Please fill out this field.';
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted but the only problem is that how do i add border to that entire block along with that triangle.It will be a great help if you help me with that@Mark Perera..

Comment: Sorry, can only add a border to the box, not the triangle as the triangle is the border. See https://jsfiddle.net/352k4ope/7/

Comment: Triangle is the border

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/352k4ope/9/. If `::before(n)` existed, it could have been done

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are asking for CSS help. 
Instead of using `p` tag try to use `span` with following CSS

```
#sym {
background-color: darkorange;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
border: 1px solid white;
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin-right: 8px;
}
```

**Edit**

I have used the CSS from the answer by Srikanth Reddy and here is your updated jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/352k4ope/3/

**Edit 2**

Added the orange border around white triangle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/352k4ope/5/

Comment: Thanks alot but I am having a problem with that orange color filled inside that triangle ..I want it to be white in color and its border should be orange..see if you can help me out with this..@Hitesh Riziya

Comment: @payal_suthar You can use an image there.  and just adjust its css.

Comment: @payal_suthar check Edit 2 now, it should be fine for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution....

Css

```
.input-block {
  position: relative;
}
.error-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50px;
  border:1px solid orange;
  border-radius:4px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:white;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:10px;
}
.error-block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent orange;
}
.error-icon {
  width:18px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:darkorange;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="input-block">
  Name:<input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
  <div class="error-block"><span class="error-icon">!</span>Please fill out this field.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ..Thanks alot it helped me to great extent ....Stackoverflow needs people like you who are ready to help others ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Html:

```
<form>
    <ul class="errorMessages"></ul>

    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="comments">Address:</label>
        <textarea id="comments" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery

```
 var createAllErrors = function() {
            var form = $( this ),
                errorList = $( "ul.errorMessages", form );

            var showAllErrorMessages = function() {
                errorList.empty();

                // Find all invalid fields within the form.
                var invalidFields = form.find( ":invalid" ).each( function( index, node ) {

                    // Find the field's corresponding label
                    var label = $( "label[for=" + node.id + "] "),
                        // Opera incorrectly does not fill the validationMessage property.
                        message = node.validationMessage || 'Invalid value.';

                    errorList
                        .show()
                        .append( "<li><span>" + label.html() + "</span> " + message + "</li>" );
                });
            };

            // Support Safari
            form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
                if ( this.checkValidity && !this.checkValidity() ) {
                    $( this ).find( ":invalid" ).first().focus();
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            $( "input[type=submit], button:not([type=button])", form )
                .on( "click", showAllErrorMessages);

            $( "input", form ).on( "keypress", function( event ) {
                var type = $( this ).attr( "type" );
                if ( /date|email|month|number|search|tel|text|time|url|week/.test ( type )
                  && event.keyCode == 13 ) {
                    showAllErrorMessages();
                }
            });
        };

        $( "form" ).each( createAllErrors );
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/352k4ope/1/)

Comment: ..Thanks alot..but even this is not working with the application i am using..Any ways thanks for answering..

Comment: Oh Thanks Mam Sorry for that@payal_suthar